# How to post a link on facebook in android by using SocialAuth?

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing app to post on Facebook and Twitter by using [socialauth-android](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/). It working fine to post message on Facebook wall but I want to post as a link along with image, how is it possible by using socialauth-android? Please guide me in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's function for posting image which is 
uploadImage(message, fileName, bitmap, quality) in socialauth-android.